# Sql - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, database

How do I update the entire row with this statement

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

But I want to update all fields besides the primary key which auto-increments. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them to the second row like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1, b=b+3, ...
```

On multiple inserts at once, you can refer to the values like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

Have look at the [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more info on syntax.

Comment: but I have many values and multiple insert statements like `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);` I was thinking that there's a shorter way :)

Comment: Edited, is that what you meant?