# Insert on SQL database or update specific value if already exsists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking forward for a way to check if the current database already contains the specified items i want to update, if it does, i only want to update one of them.

More exactly i have the following:

[image: image of the current table setup]

```
ID (Primary Key, AI)
serverID
channelID
channelROLE
```

If i'll try to add again a value that has the same serverID and channelROLE i want to update the channelID.

I've tried to use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` fuction, but can't figure it out and make it work properly for my needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql - ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889289/sql-on-duplicate-key-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ID, You can use `INSERT IGNORE`

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1
    (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
VALUES
    (....);
```

or

```
SET @id = 1,
    @serverId = 123545,
    @channelId = 512580,
    @channelRole = 'john';
INSERT INTO Table1
    (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
VALUES
    (@id, @serverId, @channelId, @channelRole)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    serverId = @serverId,
    channelId = @channelId,
    channelRole = @channelRole;
```

or Replace

```
REPLACE INTO table1
    (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
VALUES
    (...);
```

Comment: I've went for the second option you gave me, it works wonderfull, except that i need to get rid of the old "stored values"

Sadly, right now, if i try to change just the channel id, it does not update the already existing values; it just crates a new row.

Comment: you will need Unique index on it. Good luck

Comment: Well if i make / keep @id = 1 as index/primary it will just update the index key.

it updates the table properly, but i want to be able to have multiple rows stored at once that i should be able to find by the server id.

As i've set the "ID" to be auto generated.

Comment: make the ID auto generated and create unique index on other column(s) which is needed to satisfy unicity. My answer is still correct. I believe that you don't catch the point of index usage. please take your time and google it ;)

Comment: Managed to get it working and updating the values, but i've rand into another problem that i can't really find a fix for.

For some reason when i insert/update the values, they get a rounded ( Eg. from `466011936425771058` to `466011936425771060` )

If i try to add the values manually into the table it works and they don't get rounded. (this happens even if it's set as `VARCHAR` with the length set at maximum)

Answer (score 0):

> If i'll try to add again a value that has the same serverID and channelROLE i want to update the channelID.

You seem to be looking for an [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query.

```
INSERT INTO my table 
    (id, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
    VALUES('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelID = 'c';
```

For this to work you need to create a UNIQUE constraint on columns serverID and channelROLE :

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
    ADD UNIQUE my_bk (serverID, channelROLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a unique index/primary key on the table.  Presumably, this is on `id`.  If you don't have one already:

```
create index unq_table1_id on table1(id);
```

Then you can do:

```
insert into table1 (ID, serverID, channelID, channelROLE)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?)
    on duplicate key update
        serverId = values(serverId),
        channelId = values(channelId),
        channelRole = values(channelRole);
```

The `?`s are placeholders for parameter values that you are passing into the query.  The `VALUES()` function returns the value passed in for a given column.